# Can't create more than 10 assignments per HIT

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto, mechanicalturk

I'm using the code below to create a HIT on Mechanical Turk using [Boto 3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html):

```
new_hit = mturk.create_hit(
    Title='my title',
    Description='my description',
    Keywords='my, keywords',
    Reward='0.02',
    MaxAssignments=25,
    LifetimeInSeconds=9999,
    AssignmentDurationInSeconds=9999,
    AutoApprovalDelayInSeconds=9999,
    Question='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExternalQuestion xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2006-07-14/ExternalQuestion.xsd">
<ExternalURL>https://myexternalurl/</ExternalURL>
<FrameHeight>540</FrameHeight>
</ExternalQuestion>'''
)
```

This should create one HIT with 25 assignments.

However, when I try to retrieve the results, there are only 10 assignments:

```
results = mturk.list_assignments_for_hit(
    HITId='my HIT ID',
    AssignmentStatuses=['Submitted', 'Approved']
)

# This always maxes out at 10
print 'Number of assignments: ' + str(len(results['Assignments']))
```

I've tried this with several different HITs and several different `MaxAssignments` values. It always maxes out at 10 assignments. It appears that Mechanical Turk is silently capping `MaxAssignments` at 10.

I've found two clues in the Mechanical Turk documentation. First:

> HITs created with fewer than 10 assignments cannot be extended to have
>   10 or more assignments. Attempting to add assignments in a way that
>   brings the total number of assignments for a HIT from fewer than 10
>   assignments to 10 or more assignments will result in an
>   AWS.MechanicalTurk.InvalidMaximumAssignmentsIncrease exception.
>
> https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/mturk.html#MTurk.Client.create_additional_assignments_for_hit.

Second:

> If a HIT is created with 10 or more maximum assignments, there is an additional fee. For more information, see Amazon Mechanical Turk Pricing.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_CreateHITOperation.html

But this doesn't explain why I can't use a value greater than 10 for `MaxAssignments` in the first instance. I'm not getting any errors.

How can I create and retrieve more than ten assignments per HIT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried specifying the MaxResults parameter, like below:

```
response = client.list_assignments_for_hit(
    HITId='string',
    NextToken='string',
    MaxResults=123,
    AssignmentStatuses=[
        'Submitted'|'Approved'|'Rejected',
    ]
)
```

Comment: That worked. (I had to set `MaxResults=100`, since `100` is the limit, apparently.) Thanks.